# join and output - using SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like some guidance on how to write the SQL for the following without using Group By command?

Lets say I have the following table:

```
Product
PrdNo|PrdName
1|Mouse
2|Keyboard
3|Monitor
4|Speakers
5|Cpu

OrderList
OrdNo|PrdNo|Qty
101|4|2
102|3|4
103|2|1
104|1|5
105|4|3
106|5|1
107|2|4

Orders
OrdNo|OrdState
101|MD
102|CA
103|CA
104|VA
105|CA
106|NY
107|CA
```

How can display the following, for which the Orders state is CA? And Sort it ascending by product name. Make it print only unique (distinct) product name. And do not use Group By command.

```
PrdName|PrdNo||OrdState   
Keyboard|2|CA
Monitor|3|CA
Speakers|4|CA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables together and apply `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.PrdNo, p.PrdName, o.OrdState
FROM Product AS p
INNER JOIN OrderList AS ol ON p.PrdNo = ol.PrdNo
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON o.OrdNo = ol.OrdNo
WHERE o.OrdState = 'CA'
ORDER BY PrdName
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/279ca/5)